# La función no devuelve los datos correctos

Tags: javascript, poo, funciones, function, class

Estoy tratando de resolver el siguiente ejercicio y la mayoria de los codigos que pruebo no son correctos. Dejo escrito algunas partes pero no estan bien.
Agradecería si alguien me colabora o explica. Gracias!

El primero si lo hice bien

```
function crearClaseAlumno() {

  class Alumno {

      constructor (nombre, apellido, cohorte, grupoDeAmigos, notasCheckpoints) {
          // El constructor de la clase recibe nombre (string), apellido (string), cohorte (number), 
          // grupoDeAmigos (array de objetos), notasCheckpoints (array de numbers).
          // Inicializar las propiedades del alumno con los valores recibidos como argumento.
          //
          // Tu código:
          
          this.nombre = nombre;
          this.apellido = apellido;
          this.cohorte = cohorte;
          this.grupoDeAmigos = grupoDeAmigos;
          this.notasCheckpoints = notasCheckpoints;

      };
```

Este no se como resolverlo.

Este método debe agregar amigos al array de grupoDeAmigos del alumno.
Añade un objeto con las propiedades "nombre", "apellido" y "cohorte" (siendo el value de cohorte el mismo que tiene asignado la instancia de "Alumno") en el array de grupoDeAmigos.
No debe retornar nada.

```
      addAmigos(nombre, apellido) {
        
          // Tu código:  
      };
```

El siguiente lo hice mal

```
      obtenerAmigos() {
          // Este método debe devolver la cantidad de amigos que tiene el alumno.
          //
          // Tu código:
         return this.amigos.length;
      };
```

```
      addNota(nota) {
          // Este método añade una nota al array de notasCheckpoints
          // No debe retornar nada.
          //
          // Tu código:
          this.nota.push(notasCheckpoints);
          
      };
```

Como ven este tambien esta mal

```
      obtenerNotas() {
          // Este método debe devolver un array con las notas del alumno.
          //
          // Tu código:
          return this.notasCheckpoints.map;

        //tambien esta mal  
      };
```

Y este ultimo probe varias codigos pero ninguno me da bien

```
      presentacion() {
          // Este método debe devolver un string utilizando el nombre, el apellido y 
          // el cohorte del alumno.
          // Ej: Si ejecutamos presentacion() en la instancia de alumno, devolvería: 
          // "Hola, soy el alumno Lionel Messi del cohorte 13";
          //
          // Tu código:

          return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido + " " + "del" + " " + this.cohorte;

            // esta mal
      };
      
  };

  return Alumno;
};
```

Por favor si podrian ayudarme, porque no encuentro la forma de poder resolverlo.
Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es una pregunta por pregunta!!! aca hay muchisimas dudas.. si tomamos el primero por ejemplo, decis que esta mal... que error sale??

Comment: Sólo muestras los enunciados, pero no muestras cuáles fueron tus intentos fallidos. No lo haremos por ti.

Comment: Perdon! Es la primera vez que lo hago y no me dejaba escribirlo de otra forma, no me aceptaba las palabras que escribia

Comment: Mauricio si están mis intentos. Donde dice tu codigo: ahi estan mis respuestas, solo hay 1 que no tiene respuesta porque no pude hacerlo. No necesito que me lo resuelvan, sino que me puedan ayudar a entender el razonamiento asi puedo resolverlo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En la primera sección donde esta el constructor del código, como mencionas estás bien, gracias por esa aportación.

**Función agregar amigos** ---->

```
addAmigos(nombre, apellido) {
      // Este método debe agregar amigos al array de grupoDeAmigos del alumno.
      // Añade un objeto con las propiedades "nombre", "apellido" y "cohorte" (siendo 
      // el value de cohorte el mismo que tiene asignado la instancia de "Alumno") 
      // en el array de grupoDeAmigos.
      // No debe retornar nada.
      //
      // Tu código:

      this.grupoDeAmigos.push( {  nombre: nombre, apellido: apellido, cohorte: this.cohorte })
      
  };
```

**Función Obtener amigos**----->
Aquí tienes que hacer referencia en la clase constructor con el `this`

```
obtenerAmigos() {
      // Este método debe devolver la cantidad de amigos que tiene el alumno.
      //
      // Tu código:

      return this.grupoDeAmigos.length;
      
  };
```

**Función añadir nota------>**

Aquí queremos empujar la variable `nota` dentro del array que se encuentra igualmente en el constructor

```
addNota(nota) {
      // Este método añade una nota al array de notasCheckpoints
      // No debe retornar nada.
      //
      // Tu código:

      this.notasCheckpoints.push(nota);
      
  };
```

**Función Obtener notas------->**

No hay necesidad de agregar el método de `.map`, ya que la variable `notasCheckpoint` ya es un array en sí mismo.

```
obtenerNotas() {
      // Este método debe devolver un array con las notas del alumno.
      //
      // Tu código:

      return this.notasCheckpoints;
      
  };
```

**Función presentación**------->

Aquí simplemente faltó completar la sintaxis completa del enunciado como lo pide.

```
presentacion() {
      // Este método debe devolver un string utilizando el nombre, el apellido y 
      // el cohorte del alumno.
      // Ej: Si ejecutamos presentacion() en la instancia de alumno, devolvería: 
      // "Hola, soy el alumno Lionel Messi del cohorte 13";
      //
      // Tu código:

      return "Hola, soy el alumno "+this.nombre+" "+this.apellido+" del cohorte "+this.cohorte;

  };
```